# Vue.js checkout stepper

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, event-handling, vue.js

I have made this small checkout stepper with Vue (v 2.x.x):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#cart",
  data: {
    stepCounter: 1,
    steps: [{
        step: 1,
        completed: false,
        text: "Cart"
      },
      {
        step: 2,
        completed: false,
        text: "Shipping"
      },
      {
        step: 3,
        completed: false,
        text: "Payment"
      },
      {
        step: 4,
        completed: false,
        text: "Confirmation"
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    doPrev: function() {
      if (this.stepCounter > 1) {
        this.stepCounter--;
        this.doCompleted();
      }
    },
    doNext: function() {
      if (this.stepCounter <= this.steps.length) {
        this.stepCounter++;
        this.doCompleted();
      }
    },
    doCompleted: function() {
      this.steps.forEach(item => {
        item.completed = item.step < this.stepCounter;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.progressbar {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: steps;
  padding-top: 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.progressbar li {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.progressbar li.completed {
  color: #ccc;
}

.progressbar li.active {
  color: #4caf50;
}

.progressbar li::after {
  counter-increment: steps;
  content: counter(steps, decimal);
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.progressbar li.active::after,
.progressbar li.completed::after {
  background: #4caf50;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  color: #fff;
}

.progressbar li.completed::after {
  content: '\2713';
}

.progressbar li::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -26px;
  left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li.active::before,
.progressbar li.completed::before,
.progressbar li.active+li::before {
  background: #4caf50;
}

.progressbar li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="cart" class="mt-2">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="progressbar">
      <li v-for="(step, index) in steps" v-bind:class="{ active: index + 1 === stepCounter, completed: step.completed === true }">{{step.text}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="container px-4 mt-5 text-center">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" v-bind:class="{ disabled : stepCounter === 1}" @click="doPrev()">Prev</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" v-bind:class="{ disabled : stepCounter > steps.length}" @click="doNext()">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Questions

1. Is there any room for "shortening" the code?
2. Anything inconsistent at the logic level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `step` as a property inside each step is redundant and can lead to bugs if the value is incorrect. Consider what would happen if you had this:

```
data: {
  stepCounter: 1,
  steps: [{
      step: 5,
      completed: false,
      text: "Cart"
    },
    {
      step: 3,
      completed: false,
      text: "Shipping"
    },
    {
      step: 7,
      completed: false,
      text: "Payment"
    },
    {
      step: 1,
      completed: false,
      text: "Confirmation"
    }
  ]
},
```

To solve this issue, remove the `step` from the data completely.

```
data: {
  stepCounter: 1,
  steps: [{
      completed: false,
      text: "Cart"
    },
    {
      completed: false,
      text: "Shipping"
    },
    {
      completed: false,
      text: "Payment"
    },
    {
      completed: false,
      text: "Confirmation"
    }
  ]
},
```

A similar mistake can happen if the `completed` property is entered incorrectly. Instead, use the current `stepCounter` property to determine when to mark a step as completed.

---

To make the component reusable, I would recommend using some *props* instead of only *data*. Suggested props would be the `stepCounter` and the text for each step.

Preferably, I would like to see it possible to use your component like this:

`<Stepper :steps="['step one', 'step two', 'step three']" currentStep="2" />`

Answer (score 4):

> #### Is there any room for "shortening" the code?

#### Shorthands

[Shorthands](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Shorthands) can simplify the markup. The click handlers already use the shorthand `@click` instead of `v-on:click`. The bindings can be simplified as well. For example - instead of:

> ```
> v-bind:class="..."
> ```

the `v-bind` can be omitted:

```
:class="..."
```

#### Watch out!

[image: 1]

Yesterday there was [an answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/260915/120114) to [your TODO app post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/260898/120114) which suggested using [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). With the current architecture using a computed property doesn't seem feasible, but a [watcher method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) could be employed. Instead of setting up a method like `doCompleted()` that must be called manually, a watcher method can be used to adjust the values whenever that value changes.

```
watch: {
  stepCounter: function(newValue, oldValue) {
    this.steps.forEach(item => {
      item.completed = item.step < this.stepCounter;
    });
  }
},
```

Note that `newValue` could be used instead of `this.stepCounter`.

While it would occupy the same number of lines as the current code, it takes the burden off the methods `doPrev` and `doNext` of having to call the method `doCompleted`. See the demo below for an illustration of this.

```js
const makeStep = (text, index) => {return {text, step: ++index, completed: false}};
const steps = ['Cart', 'Shipping', 'Payment', 'Confirmation'].map(makeStep);
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#cart",
  data: {
    stepCounter: 1,
    steps
  },
  watch: {
    stepCounter: function(newValue, oldValue) {
      this.steps.forEach(item => {
        item.completed = item.step <  this.stepCounter;
      });
    }
  },
  methods: {
    doPrev: function() {
      if (this.stepCounter > 1) {
        this.stepCounter--;
      }
    },
    doNext: function() {
      if (this.stepCounter <= this.steps.length) {
        this.stepCounter++;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.progressbar {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: steps;
  padding-top: 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.progressbar li {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.progressbar li.completed {
  color: #ccc;
}

.progressbar li.active {
  color: #4caf50;
}

.progressbar li::after {
  counter-increment: steps;
  content: counter(steps, decimal);
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -15px;
}

.progressbar li.active::after,
.progressbar li.completed::after {
  background: #4caf50;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  color: #fff;
}

.progressbar li.completed::after {
  content: '\2713';
}

.progressbar li::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -26px;
  left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li.active::before,
.progressbar li.completed::before,
.progressbar li.active+li::before {
  background: #4caf50;
}

.progressbar li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="cart" class="mt-2">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="progressbar">
      <li v-for="(step, index) in steps" :class="{ active: index + 1 === stepCounter, completed: step.completed }">{{step.text}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="container px-4 mt-5 text-center">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" :class="{ disabled : stepCounter === 1}" @click="doPrev()">Prev</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" :class="{ disabled : stepCounter > steps.length}" @click="doNext()">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the data structure can be modified such that the *completed* property isn't needed, then the markup could use the condition `step.step < stepCounter` to determine when the `completed` class is added to each list item. See the snippet below for a demonstration of this.

```js
const makeStep = (text, index) => {return {text, step: ++index}};
const steps = ['Cart', 'Shipping', 'Payment', 'Confirmation'].map(makeStep);
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#cart",
  data: {
    stepCounter: 1,
    steps
  },
  methods: {
    doPrev: function() {
      if (this.stepCounter > 1) {
        this.stepCounter--;
      }
    },
    doNext: function() {
      if (this.stepCounter <= this.steps.length) {
        this.stepCounter++;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.progressbar {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: steps;
  padding-top: 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.progressbar li {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.progressbar li.completed {
  color: #ccc;
}

.progressbar li.active {
  color: #4caf50;
}

.progressbar li::after {
  counter-increment: steps;
  content: counter(steps, decimal);
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -15px;
}

.progressbar li.active::after,
.progressbar li.completed::after {
  background: #4caf50;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  color: #fff;
}

.progressbar li.completed::after {
  content: '\2713';
}

.progressbar li::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -26px;
  left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li.active::before,
.progressbar li.completed::before,
.progressbar li.active+li::before {
  background: #4caf50;
}

.progressbar li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="cart" class="mt-2">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="progressbar">
      <li v-for="(step, index) in steps" v-bind:class="{ active: index + 1 === stepCounter, completed: step.step < stepCounter }">{{step.text}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="container px-4 mt-5 text-center">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" v-bind:class="{ disabled : stepCounter === 1}" @click="doPrev()">Prev</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" v-bind:class="{ disabled : stepCounter > steps.length}" @click="doNext()">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS: margin rules

The ruleset `.progressbar li::after {` contains these rules:

> ```
> margin-left: -15px;
> margin-top: -60px;
> ```

Presuming there is no margin inherited from other elements for the right and bottom, those can be combined into a single rule:

```
margin: -60px 0 0 -15px;
```

Comment: Nitpick: wouldn't your `margin: -60px 0 0 -15px;` override some right/bottom margin defined earlier in the chain, while the two separate definition's don't?

Comment: Good catch- I considered it and should have mentioned it. I have updated that section accordingly. Thanks!